# Get the line number of a mutiline textbox that contains a string

Tags: vb.net, textbox, contains

For example, if a mutiline textbox has the string "apple" in one of the lines how do I get the line number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.IndexOf`:

```
Dim indexOfText = Array.IndexOf(textBox1.Lines, "apple")
```

If you want to find a string which can be a part of the line, also searching case-insensitive:

```
indexOfText = Array.FindIndex(textBox1.Lines, Function(str) str.IndexOf("apple", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Since indices are zero based you need to add 1 if you want the line number(in case the index isn't -1).

Comment: Then use a RichTextBox or ListBox. Apart from that, `IndexOf` is very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a RichTextBox which has a `GetLineFromCharIndex` method which you can use the `.Text.IndexOf` method to get the index.

Comment: i would use a richtextbox. the standard textbox is so... slow... try dumping stdout to a textbox at 1000 lines per second compared to richtextbox :D custom OnPaint of course.